# I don't understand why my program to find prime numbers is working?

Tags: c++, primes

I'm currently learning C++ and I just created a simple program to find prime numbers :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main() {


// VARIABLES

int num = 3;
int divisor = 2;
const int max = 1000000;
bool prime = true;

// BOUCLE

while (num <= max) {
    while (divisor <= (num / 2)) {
        if ( (num % divisor) == 0) {
            prime = false;
            divisor = 2;
            break;
        }
        divisor++;
    }
    if (prime == true) {
        cout << num << endl;
    }
prime = true;
num++;
}
}
```

My question is about the divisor integer : if the number tested is not prime, the "divisor = 2" line is never executed, so how is my loop working fine?
Example : 11 is tested. 11 is a prime number, so the if statement is never executed, but the int divisor value is now 5. Then 12 is tested, starting with the divisor 5. This should cause an error, no?

Comment: "If the number tested is not prime, the `divisor = 2` line is never executed": yes it is. Right after `prime = false;`. But there are far better algorithms than this. Look up the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: Why do you assume that line is never executed?

Comment: The real problem here is that if the number ***is*** prime `divisor` never gets reset. Which means that your code is incorrect. The correct place to initialize `divisor` is after the first `while` statement, not where it is now.

Comment: @user207421 I thought all the lines between the { } following the if statement were not executed if the condition was not true (for prime numbers, num % divisor == 0 cannot be true)

Comment: If `num % divisor == 0` the number isn't prime. Not the other way round. That's why you set `prime = false` when the condition is satisfied. And set `divisor = 2`. And stop testing it with `break`.

Comment: @user207421 thank you for your reply! Curiously the code seems to work correctly. I do not understand why and that's why I made this post. I'll try moving the initialization line at the correct place!

Comment: It can't possibly be correct. You are reporting numbers as prime that aren't, because you aren't testing all possible factors, because you aren't resetting `divisor`.

Comment: @user207421 that's what I thought too but it really seems to work as it is. I really cannot understand why but every number generated up to 1000 is prime...

Comment: @user207421 `divisor <= num/divisor` has an advantage over `divisor*divisor <= num` as the later one incurs `int` overflow when `num` is a prime near `INT_MIN`.  The former does not.  It also does not incur an added time as a good compiler sees the nearby `num/divisor` and `num%divisor` and does both for the time cost of one.

Comment: It is as least partly because when you get past the point where `divisor*divisor <= num` you start effectively repeating tests for the smaller divisors. A proper algorithm would stop at this point instead of iterating until `divisor > num/2`. @chux-ReinstateMonica Agreed.

Comment: Comment should have been "incurs `int` overflow when num is a prime near `INT_MAX`".  Also `int ` overflow is UB, so wrap around to small test divisors is not certain.

Comment: Why would testing 12 starting with the divisor 5 cause an error? Even if you did start with 5 (you don't; you start at 6) you would continue to the next divisor, 6, and find `12 % 6 == 0`.

Comment: @molbdnilo when OP's code start testing 5, it starts with divisor 2 not 6.  divisor was reset to 2 due to prior failed prime test for 4.

Answer (score 1):

> how is my loop working fine?

Code only resets the initial divisor to 2 when a non-prime is found, but not when a prime is found.

```
    // When true, `num` is _not a prime.
    if ( (num % divisor) == 0) {
        prime = false;
        divisor = 2;
        break;
    }
```

Normally the `divisor = 2;` should happen before each new `num`.

Since code is incrementing, after a prime is found the next `num` is even and that eventually `(num % divisor) == 0` is true.  Thus resetting things properly.

A better prime test for reference.

```
  while (num <= max) {
    // Set first divisor here
    int divisor = 2;
    prime = true;
    // Iterate to the sqrt, not num/2 --> much faster
    while (divisor <= num / divisor) {
      if (num % divisor == 0) {
        prime = false;
        break;
      }
      divisor++;
    }
    if (prime && num > 3) {
      cout << num << endl;
    }
    num++;
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question as to why it works up to 1000. There are far better algorithms than this.

Comment: @user207421 OP is looking to understand why the code posted in the question works, buts thinks it should not.  That is answered here.  This answer also provides an O(sqrt(n)) test that is the next step to improved prime detection (OP's was O(n)).  Significant differ approaches like [sieve of eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) do incur large memory requirements and while a good idea, do not well address OP's plight.  Of course even better approach exists for larger scale prime test tasks.

Comment: All you've done here is restate the OP's question. You haven't answered it.

Comment: @user207421 Paragraph ending "...Thus resetting things properly." answers why code work "fine."

Answer (score 1):

The reason this works is number theory: you're testing all the even numbers too, and that will *always* reset your divisor down to 2, ready to do the next test on an odd number (which *may* or may not be prime).

So let's go past 11 and 12, and go to 13.  Your loop will break out of that with a `divisor` value of `7` and (correctly) mark 13 as prime.  Then it'll increment num to `14`, and that test will go into your `prime=false;` section, resetting `divisor` to 2.  Bottom of the loop, testing for `15` now.  And the divisor was reset to `2` and you're good, since your code will cycle through `3` as the `divisor` and `15` will be marked as non-prime (correctly).  Then `16` will reset `divisor` again, ready for `17`.  Etc.

If you were *more* clever and only testing odds (if it was `num+=2` not `num++` at the end), then this case would actually break, since 7 is above the largest factor of 15, and would erroneously say prime.  But because you are testing even numbers, and *at worst* divisor will be half of the number, it'll get reset.

Answer (score 1):

When you find a composite number, you reset `divisor` to 2, so that's not a problem.
(It is very unclear why you believe that line isn't executed – is that a typo?)

When you find a prime, the next `num` is going to be even, and the first `divisor` you test is `num / 2` (when you're "done" with 11, the first `divisor` is 6, not 5).

And since `num` is even, `num / 2` divides `num` (if `a` divides `b`, then so does `b/a`).